# Excel VBA Job : Updation of master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

**Scenario :**
I had 2 workbooks, First one is a "master" workbook and other one is a "servant" workbook or in other terms "servant" workbook is a subset of "master" workbook, both workbooks contain a column known as "Commodity", "master" workbook contains exhaustive list of all items where "servant" workbook has few of those items, but it contains new updated values corresponding to those few items.

**Job given to me :**
I had to manually first pick the commodity from "servant" workbook find that "commodity" in "master" workbook and update the master workbook with the new values which are populated in "servant" workbook.

Why I had to find each commodity manually is because sorting of data in both sheets doesn't match.

My Code :

```
Sub Macro4()
    '
    ' Macro4 Macro
    '
    Windows("test2.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A2:A15").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Test.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B2:B15").Select
    Windows("test2.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B2:B15").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Test.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you paste your first code attempt?

Comment: This isn't a pair programming website, this is a website about answering specific questions to specific problems you have. This post doesn't have a specific question, just a request to help you fulfill requirements. Please have a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I know it looks very simple, but still the problem in this code is it fetches first 15 results , it doesn't check the content of the cell, but only paste first 15 values from "servant" sheet to corresponding first 15 cells in master sheet irrespective of whether the content of first 15 values are equal in both "master" & "servant" sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you seek but I do not believe anyone could give it to you.

What you are asking for appears to be a very simple VBA macro.  If you do not know enough VBA to write that macro, I do not believe you would understand it if it was given to you.

You must learn the basics.  Search the web for “Excel VBA tutorial”.  There are many to choose from so try a few and complete the one that matches your learning style.  I prefer books.  I visited a good library, reviewed their Excel VBA Primers and borrowed those I preferred to try at home.  Finally I bought the one I liked the best as a permanent reference book.

I do not know how quickly you will absorb the key concepts of programming in Excel VBA.  Some find those concepts obvious while for others programming is an alien world where they will never be happy.  I suggest you invest half-a-day in studying VBA.  If you are finding VBA reasonably easy to understand then start thinking about your macro.

The code you present has been created by the Excel Macro Recorder.  The macro recorder is a great way of identifying the VBA statements corresponding to a keyboard function but it is not a good way to learn VBA.  It will not help much with your macro.

The tutorial should explain the difference between “workbook” and “worksheet”.  A workbook is a file saved to disk.  “test2.xlsx” and “Test.xlsx” are workbooks.  A workbook will contain one or more worksheets.   A worksheet contains row and columns.  In your question you use “workbook” for both workbooks and worksheets.

You will need to design your macro.  For a simple macro, the easiest approach if often to record how you would approach the task manually:

```
Open master workbook.
Open servant workbook.
Within Servant workbook look at worksheet containing Commodity column.
For each entry in this column:
  Search for matching entry in Community column of master workbook.
  If matching entry found
    Copy select values from servant row to master row
  If matching entry not found
    Record error or take corrective action.
Next
Save master workbook.
```

Assuming I have understood your question, the above list is the structure of your macro.  Most lines in the list correspond to one, or a few, simple VBA statements that you should have learnt from your tutorial.

In your macro you have already opened the master and servant workbooks. A VBA macro in one workbook can open other workbooks.  Once you have a little experience, you will probably find this the most convenient approach.  However, I suggest you leave multi-workbook macros to stage 2.  I suggest you create a development workbook containing a copy of the master worksheet and the servant worksheet.  Get your macro working within that single workbook first then update for multiple workbooks.  I usually find it best to have macros in a workbook not assessable by the regular users.  This macro will open both the master and servant workbooks.

I hope this gives you a start.  Most people do not find programming in Excel VBA too difficult once they have mastered the basics.  However, trying to find snippets of code on the web before you have mastered those basics is at best difficult and slow and often impossible.